# What is the security update policy for old versions of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the VS Code approach & policy on security updates for old (non-latest) versions? For example, if the latest version is 1.86, and there is a CVE discovered in 1.85, will there be a minor release made available for 1.85 to address the CVE?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see browsing the advisories at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/security, no, they don't backport fixes to previous minor versions. In the advisories there, you'll typically see something like this:

> Description: [...] exists in VS Code <version X> and earlier versions [...]
>
> Patches: The fix is available starting with VS Code <some version after version X>

Also, in general, VS Code follows a monthly release cadence where the end of the each month has a new minor release, followed by a few recovery (patch) releases https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases (also see [the release docs page](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates)). They adhere to that pattern pretty consistently. I.e. they don't go back to patch past minor releases after releasing the next one.